# Socket level statistics in Linux/Unix

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming

Is there a way to programmatically know the total number of raw bytes sent or received by a socket in Linux/Unix?

Comment: Read() and write() function in socket programming returns the number of bytes recieved and sent respectively. Just take the sum of these values.

Comment: @shivammitra, Aren't those the number of payload bytes?

Comment: I suspect it's not in there because it's not always possible to associate a byte to a single socket. What if you're connecting over a VPN, and packets for two different connections get encapsulated in a single VPN packet, and the VPN packet has some overhead?

Comment: As far as I know, no. The statistics are maintained per device (see `/proc/net/dev`) and per process (see `/proc/PID/net/dev`) in Linux, and they include the number of bytes in the payload and number of packets and so on. (The device-specific statistics at `/sys/class/net/*/statistics/*` are the same values, just one field per pseudofile.) In many cases (accelerated network cards) the kernel might never know the actual number of bytes/symbols sent/received on the wire anyway, so it'd be messy/futile to even try to account it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337249/good-documentation-on-structure-tcp-info There is everything you need to know how to collect statistics from the socket on Linux/BSD.

Comment: `/proc/PID/net/dev` contains the same data as `/proc/net/dev` (like a symbolic link), so it's not suitable for this task.

Answer (score 0):

try  the following:

```
int l = 0;
ioctl(sock, FIONREAD, &l);
if (l > 0)
{
  l = read(sock, buffer, l);
}
```

Comment: Will `l` contain the number of raw bytes of application bytes only?

Comment: yes, The FIONREAD ioctl returns the number of data bytes in all data messages queued