# Which direction (inbound or outbound) does TCP_INFO returned from getsockopt give?

Tags: tcp, linux-kernel, getsockopt

The tcp_info structs provides useful stats about the current TCP connection. However, I am unsure which `flow` these stats refer to.

For a bidirectional connection, meaning a `fd` is both read from and written to, what does some of the stat refer to? The outbound flow or the inbound flow?

Eg. does `tcp_info.tcpi_rcv_space` refer to the *receive buffer size of the inbound flow of the local machine, i.e., the receive buffer of the local machine*, or the *advertised size of the receive buffer of the outbound flow to the remote machine, i.e., receive buffer of the remote machine*?

Many thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337249/good-documentation-on-structure-tcp-info

Comment: hmm. I have checked that link, but I don't think there is any information on the actual question?